# Discord Python Rewrite - Move channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

Is it possible to move a channel on discord.py? Im making a nuke command that clones and deletes the channel, and it worked, but now i need to find out how to move the channel up to the origonal place, if there's a code / docs, please tell me a example. Thank's

Edit:
I Got a working edit but it's always drags it on top, i need it so it will drag the channel to the same position before it got nuked.

My code that i currently have

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def nuke(ctx):

    channel = ctx.channel

    await channel.clone()
    await channel.delete()
    await channel.edit(position=0, sync_permissions=True)
    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`await channel.edit(position=0)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.edit) to change the position. In this case, since `0` is specified, the channel will be moved to the first position.

If you want to move it to the deleted channel's position then you can check [`channel.position`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.TextChannel.position).

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_channels=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    
    channel = ctx.channel
    channel_position = channel.position
    
    new_channel = await channel.clone()
    await channel.delete()
    await new_channel.edit(position=channel_position, sync_permissions=True)
    return
```

Comment: i mean, like it moves the channel to the original spot
example:
the channel is on middle and i nuke that channel, then it will instantly move the channel back in the place, wich is middle.

Comment: Check the channels position and then once you delete it and create the replacement, edit the new one to take the same position. If you want specific code then I suggest editing your question to show what you already have.

Comment: it dindt move the channel ;-;

Comment: Apologies, the code was editing the `channel` that was deleted. Fixed now.